# getting jquery timepicker working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery and can't seem to get this basic timepicker working: https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#timepicker-plugin-for-jquery

In scripts (I renamed the folder):

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    $('#AddJustPlayForm_Time').timepicker();
})
```

In html:

```
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.AddJustPlayForm.Time, "BootstrapHorizontalTime", new { @class = "time-picker", style = "width:100px" })
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: <input type="text" id="AddJustPlayForm_Time"> add this to your page and check

Comment: what error you are getting ? & have you incliuded jquery ? o_O

Comment: Can you check if the razor generated editor have really the id **AddJustPlayForm_Time** ? Also, is your js script tag befor or after the razor tag (eq : is it in the begining or the end of the page ?)

Comment: I tried adding <input type="text" id="AddJustPlayForm_Time"> and when i inspect the element it shows the right id. I'm using resharper and in the script part it says 'can't find usage of id 'AddJustPlayForm_Time', even though that id clearly exists.

Answer (score 0):

You want to target `.time-picker` class rather than the field name for AddJustPlayForm.Time

Try

```
$(function () {

    $('.time-picker').timepicker();
})
```

You should also include the css in header.

Comment: Unfortunately that also didn't work even though it is picking up the class. Here is the text from 'inspect element':                                           <input class="timepick-input time-picker form-control" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Time must be a date." id="AddJustPlayForm_Time" name="AddJustPlayForm.Time" style="display:inline;width:60px" type="text" value="">

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had the timepicker script before the main jquery script, so it wasn't able to access the main jquery library or something along those lines. Thanks for help anyway.